# can we receive @RequestParam in object

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, mongodb-query

```
@RequestParam(value = "searchData", required = false) SearchData searchData)
```

`searchData` is having 2 variables of string type one for accepting param value and one for search parameter
,but it is showing that conversion type error cant convert string to object,  and it is showing that parameter received is `null`.

Comment: Answer here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you should define the controller method without annotation

`@RequestParam(value = "searchData", required = false)`

Just use:`(SearchData searchData)`

When called with no parameters, the object `searchData` will have all attributes set to null.

All attributes will be set to null, also in case if you use a parameter name that is not equal to one of the attribute names of `SearchData`.
For example in the case of misspelling (you have SearchData.name, and in call you have used names='someanme'). No error will be thrown.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , just for clarification if you clear my doubt that would be a great help, if this --> @RequestParam(value = "searchData", required = false) SearchData searchData)    is showing null value received and says cannot convert string to object , than why its not giving error , it seems to be a valid syntax

Comment: Yes, that's a good question. Honestly, without debugging spring, I can not give 100% accurate answer. But in my opinion, it has to do with mappers. Spring MVC can map automatically simple values (string, boolean, int), and hi is, of course, expecting that URI query param is a simple value (represented by string), otherwise, it could not be passed in URL. If not appropriate mapper is found, value is assumed as not present.

Comment: Not to forget, when calling REST defined as `(SearchData searchData)` only. The parameters in URL should be named as properties of SearchData class.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use RequestBody annotaion and provide value in the form of json object.

```
@RequestBody SearchData searchData
```